# Table header in IE8 with quirks mode on

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-8

I feel this is a basic question but couldn't find a solution here.

I have an html page to be displayed on IE8 (quirks mode). Sadly, the headers are not using all the space they should, and are displayed over several lines instead of one. The same html source works on chrome/firefox, but not ie8 with quirks mode on.

What should I do to get chrome's result on IE8? no multi-browser support is needed, only IE8.

The document:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.color5 {background-color:#DBEAF5;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%"  cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0  class="color6"    >
  <TR id="ED_ACTIONPLAN1_TR_1"  class="color5" >
<TD    WIDTH="47" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER ></TD>
<TD    WIDTH="86" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Code</TD>
<TD    WIDTH="285" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Libelle</TD>
<TD    WIDTH="86" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Priorite</TD>
<TD    WIDTH="86" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Date de debut effective</TD>
<TD    WIDTH="109" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Date d'echeance reelle</TD>
<TD    WIDTH="86" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Taux de realisation</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

The images are from the top right part of my 1920x1080 screen.

Chrome:

[image: chrome version]

IE8:

[image: IE8 version]

Comment: You don't need the `<!-- -->` around your CSS.  Also, you should be using CSS for the widths instead of using the `width` attribute.

Comment: Why do you have a `</TD>` outside of your `<TABLE>`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat the html is generated. I have done some cleaning but missed those. Thks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this style.

```
<style type="text/css">
   .color5 {background-color:#DBEAF5;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;text-align:center;width:auto;padding:5px}
</style>
```

Comment: Actually it does not solve my problem: I just get bigger columns. I wish to keep the per column widths.

Answer (score 0):

add `white-space: pre;` in class then it will in single line at IE

Comment: you mean `.color5 {background-color:#DBEAF5;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;white-space: pre;}` ?  It does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are giving the `td` elements fixed values (*which are treated as pixels*) to a table that has width 100% (*which means that its actual pixel size varies depending on browser size*).

Older versions of IE will wrap the text at the specified fixed size, and your text does not fit in 86 nor 109 pixels..

If you convert your fixed numbers to percentages it works

So, you current pixel values add up to a total of 785 pixels. if you do your math you get this

```
<TABLE WIDTH="100%"  cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0  class="color6">
    <TR id="ED_ACTIONPLAN1_TR_1"  class="color5" >
        <TD WIDTH="6.02%" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER ></TD>
        <TD WIDTH="10.95%" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Code</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="36.30%" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Libelle</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="10.95%" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Priorite</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="10.95%" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Date de debut effective</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="13.88%" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Date d'echeance reelle</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="10.95%" class="color5" ALIGN=CENTER >Taux de realisation</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

**Working demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4qhPZ/1/embedded/result/